# Bootstrap Background Image Not Displaying

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Newbie here with something that is stumping me when displaying a background image. Everything works fine when I link to an image like so:

```
.backg {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://formdoctors.com/creese79/msc/pages/med_background.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

But when I try to point to the image path like so the background won't come up.

```
.backg {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(med_background.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

If I can link to it I'm assuming the name is correct, its there in the folder and it displays perfectly, the CSS is correct and isn't being overridden elsewhere. Why can I use the first method but not the second??

Comment: Is the image in the same folder as the web page? What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: The image path should be relative to the css file's path. So if the css and images both are in that pages folder you should be fine just remember to put single-quotes around your image name. Else if the css is in css folder under pages folder put '../med_background,jpg'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the image and CSS stylesheet in same folder as the HTML page?

Check the file path of the image and CSS file. The path should be relative to the CSS file, not HTML file.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was assuming the path was relative to my page but it was from the CSS file itself. Sorry for such a dumb question.